# How to download edited PDF using ITextSharp and C# Blazor

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, blazor

I have a Blazor application in which I'm trying to download a PDF I have edited using ITextSharp. All resources I search tend to use the Response class which I don't have (I believe because I am using .NET 6). I found some solutions that that send the byte array to a javascript function but I'm having no such luck. I get the error

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.' When I Envoke the JS function.

I've posted my code below. Though I'm not passing any null objects, I do see some potential errors in my memory stream and I'm not sure why (See Image). Any information on where I'm going wrong or any easy approach would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("MY_SOURCE_PATH_CHANGED_FOR_POST");
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output);

    // Make Edits
    //editPdf(ref pdfStamper.AcroFields);
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
    pdfStamper.Close();

    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("saveAsFile", "test.pdf", output.ToArray());
```

And the JS

```
function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64)
{
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var data = window.atob(bytesBase64);
        var bytes = new Unit8Array(data.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([bytes.buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else
    {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

*Note for the sake of the post I changed the source path but I have verified the path does return a PDF, from a direct URL from azure blob storage.

[image]

Comment: That C# code is running on the server or on the client? I ask this because although it is C# the browser is still sandboxed, you cannot read/writes files on the client side machine. So if your `MY_SOURCE_PATH_CHANGED_FOR_POST` is a local path, it will not work from the browser.

Comment: Server side, I confirmed the source was working. I found a solution below though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who needs it, I solved this issue by creating a controller.

```
    [HttpGet("{appId}/{formCode}")]
    public FileContentResult DownloadForm(int appId, int formCode)
    {
        byte[] PdfData = Repo.GetFormBytes(appId, (Enums.FormType)formCode);
        if (PdfData != null)
        {
            FileContentResult file = new FileContentResult(PdfData, "application/pdf");
            file.FileDownloadName = Repo.MostRecentFileName;
            return file;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Where GetFormBytes returns byte array `output.ToArray()` after it was edited. (See question).

Comment: Please see above my Answer (comments) what is the reason my file is not download in browser.